# jquery remove particular accordion class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby, haml

This code runs fine in fiddle:
[You can expand/collapse all items and also expand/collapse individual items](http://jsfiddle.net/HqXMN/19/).

Now I have added some logic in ruby (i cannot add that in jsfiddle)

```
.accordion-body{id: "collapse-#{index}", class: ( get_office_id.to_i == office_id ? '' : 'collapse') }
```

The code above receives an id from a URL and checks it with one of the items in the accordion and expands that accordion. That works fine.

But when I click on *Expand/Collapse All*, it expands/collapses all except that one.

I tried adding the following line in my javascript above but it did not work:

```
 $(this).removeClass('accordion-body');
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You missed closing quote. 
Change $(this).removeClass('accordion-body); to
$(this).removeClass('accordion-body');

Comment: @Kabamaru.that was typo when i copied in this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code that determines whether it needs to open one of the accordion items. If it matches the ID from the url, give the `.accordion-body` classes: `collapse` and `in`

Just a guess with the ruby, but something like this?

```
.accordion-body{id: "collapse-#{index}", class: ( get_office_id.to_i == office_id ? 'collapse in' : 'collapse') }
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/n1ck/HqXMN/20/